# Angular router.navigate to child redirects to 404 route instead

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have an issue navigating to a child component from the parent.

My app-routing is look like this:

```
 const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'home',
      pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
      path: 'parent',
      component: ParentComponent,
      children: [{
          path: 'child',
          component: ChildComponent
      }]
    },
    {
      path: '404',
      component: PageNotFoundComponent
    },
    {
      path: '**',
      redirectTo: '404'
    }
];

  @NgModule({
    imports: [
      RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    providers: [{
        provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
        useValue: '/'
    }],
    exports: [
      RouterModule
    ],
  })

  export class AppRoutingModule {

  }
```

and in the parent component I call this to navigate to the child on a button click:

```
this.router.navigate(['child', { relativeTo: this.route }]);
```

but I end up in 404 page instead.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
 this.router.navigate(['../child'], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

According to The documentation  your are missing two dots

You can read about it [here (Angular NavigationExtras)](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras)

Comment: Tried but the same problem. Not sure but wondering if it is related to  providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }],

Comment: i don't know this , I'm not using it in my applications . but from what i understand
 If you're using PathLocationStrategy, you must provide a provider to a string representing the URL prefix that should be preserved when generating and recognizing URLs.

maybe try not use it and see what happen

Comment: I was wrong. It seems it has no effect with or without it. But it seems that I had an error in my component that caused this redirect. Now the Url in the browser is updated well to the child path but the Child Component is not rendered and I don't see any error in my output.

Comment: the url works fine with the ../child solution ?. 
if you want you can show show the code in the component and we will see whats the bug

Comment: this.router.navigate(['child', { relativeTo: this.route }]); works now I mean updates the url but the component is not rendered. I may have mixed the child routing concept. I see in the @planet_hunter sample there is another   <router-outlet></router-outlet> which I have only this in app.component not the parent component.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this stackblitz POC](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ld9nt) where I have used your routing configuration to redirect to child component

To redirect from parent I used following code -

```
public showChild(): void {
    this._Router.navigate(['child'], {
    relativeTo: this._ActivatedRoute
  })
}
```

To redirect from root component. I used following code -

```
public showChild(): void {
  this._Router.navigate(['parent', 'child'], {
    relativeTo: this._ActivatedRoute
  })
}
```

> EDIT - Relative Approach

To have relative route use following code -

```
public showChild(): void {
    this._Router.navigate(['./child'], {
    relativeTo: this._ActivatedRoute
  })
}
```

So if you want to go to `parent route's siblings child` e.g. `/parent1/child` from `/parent` we would have used `../parent1/child`